# how nested for loop works with R

Tags: r

I am new to R, Using nested loops, create a vector that only contains all the 2 letter combinations where at least 1 letter is a vowel (a, e, i, o, u, and y).  Make sure that your vector is in alphabetical order. I write a bunch of codes but these aren't correct completely.

```r
words<-NULL
vowel<-c("a","e","i","o","u","y")
index<-0


for(letter_1 in letters ){
  for(letter_2 in letters)
  if(any(letter_1)|any(letter_2 ==vowel)){
   index<-index+1
   words[index]<-(paste(letter_1,letter_2,sep=""))
  }
}
words
```

Comment: Your if statement should be `(letter_1 %in% vowel | letter_2 %in% vowel)`

Comment: Or `any(c(letter_1, letter_2) %in% vowel)`.

Answer (score 1):

While the nested loop will work fine, R is a vectorized language so this would be a more R-like solution:

```
combos <- expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS)[, 2:1]
dim(combos)
# [1] 676   2     There are 676 permutations of two letters
vowels <- c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
idx <- apply(combos, 1, function(x) any(unlist(x) %in% vowels))
result <- combos[idx, ]
dim(result)
# [1] 235   There are 235 with at least one vowel
head(result)
#   Var2 Var1
# 1    A    A
# 2    A    B
# 3    A    C
# 4    A    D
# 5    A    E
# 6    A    F
tail(result)
#     Var2 Var1
# 645    Y    U
# 651    Z    A
# 655    Z    E
# 659    Z    I
# 665    Z    O
# 671    Z    U
```